# Folder appears as a file over Android MTP connection

Tags: windows-10, backup, android, mtp

So I am trying to backup the folders of my Android phone via MTP connection on a Windows 10 PC using a USB cable.

Most of the folders work as intended but there is one folder that shows up as an extensionless single (36.0 KB (36,864.00 bytes)) file in File Explorer.

I've tried renaming the folder within the Android phone or rebooting the phone and PC altogether but with no luck. The folder and files inside appear healthy on the phone with no signs of corruption.

How is this possible? I've never seen anything like this ever.

Comment: What folder is it? What's in the file you see on PC?

Comment: While I can't answer your question, it's more efficient to transfer files between a PC and an Android device via enabling USB Debugging and using `adb` on the PC.  To enable USB Debugging: Settings > About Phone > tap Build Number 7x > go back to Settings > System > Developer Options > USB Debugging - Enable.  On the PC, install [`platform-tools`](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools), open a terminal within the `platform-tools` directory: **Device => PC:** `adb pull -p /sdcard/<file/directory> C:\dir\path` || **PC => Device:** `adb push -p C:\dir\path /sdcard`

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps this isn't a folder but is instead a symbolic link or hard link of some kind perhaps? In any case, as already suggested, you may want to try a transfer method other than MTP. If using `adb` doesn't suit you, you can also likely download an FTP server application for your Android device and connect it to your local wireless network. You can then use a Windows compatible FTP client such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) to try and transfer the folder contents.